# Fourcc in cv2 issues

Tags: opencv, python-2.7, fourcc

```
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','2','6','4')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'VideoWriter_fourcc'
```

I keep getting this error while using fourcc. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: VideoWriter_fourcc is from the opencv 3.0(master) api.

Answer (score 7):

You should use `fourcc = cv2.cv.CV_FOURCC(*'X264')`